# AngularJS add conditional class in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with some AngularJS ng-repeat looping, but I want to generate the markup of a grid, but need to add a 'grid--last' class to the 4th item in the grid, is this achievable?

My HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="service in services" class="grid__4">
                <div class="services__box">
                    <img src="img/services/{{service.thumb}}.jpg" alt="" class="services__box__img">
                    <h1 class="services__box--alpha alpha">{{service.title}}</h1>
                    <p>
                        {{service.text}}
                    </p>
                    <a href="{{service.url}}.php" class="services__box--btn btn btn--blue">{{service.button}}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Ideally I need to get the index of the array and use ng-class. Can anybody shed some light as to how I could do this? Thanks!

```
ng-class="{}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular repeat scope provide an `$index` property; therefore, you can do `data-ng-class="{'grid--last': $index == 3}"` assuming you mean that 4th item is 3 since index start at 0.

Comment: Thanks! Just tried it, however it doesn't work :( can you advise on the HTML usage to make sure I'm doing it correctly? Thanks again.

Comment: Console error actually: Error: Syntax Error: Token '-' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 6

Comment: Does work infact, but my hyphens aren't letting it work. Any ideas how I can fix that? :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the hyphen.  You could wrap it around single quote: 'grid--last': $index == 3

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with CSS, but there may be browser compatibility issues with IE8 and lower (shocking)

[plnk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/z1lVUZLP5SYeuWNxEBmc?p=preview)

relevant code:

```
<style>
      li.item {
        background-color:blue;
      }

      li.item:last-child {
       background-color: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="testCtl">
    <ul>
      <li class="item" ng-repeat="val in [1, 2, 3, 4]">{{val}}</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```